# background for text area using HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I placed a background for textarea with borders as black, changed the border radius and did few other styling. The end result shows a line on top of my customized text area and i am not sure how to remove it. Can you please help? I am sure that i didn;t place that line myself.
css:

```
#login {
    height:5%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:3%;
    left:0%;
    width:97%;
    height:32px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #ffffff 25%,
        #ffffff 50%,
        #ffffff 75%,
        #dadce8
    );
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#ffffff),
        color-stop(0.25, #ffffff),
        color-stop(0.50, #ffffff),
        color-stop(0.75, #ffffff),
        to(#dadce8)
    );
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your markup, CSS styles, and if at all possible a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Can you provide your exact code please? http://jsfiddle.net <--

Comment: `<div data-role="page">
 <header data-role='header' data-mini="true"><h1>Login</h1></header>
 
 <div data-role="content" id="content">
 <form><div id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="login" required placeholder="Enter Username"></div>`

Comment: Thats my markup and css

Comment: i tried your same scenario and didnt find ny line..which browser did u tried?

Comment: I didnt find any line too. may be your remaining code has some problem

Comment: `#form1{
top:96px;
position:absolute;
right:5%;
left:4.5%;
}`

Comment: If we use this alone, i am not seeing anything. I am also using the css provided by jQueryMobile for that HTML... That is causing the problem...

Comment: I finally found the solution. Need to add data-role="none" for the input tag... Yahooo.